# Printing an axis variable on two lines in sgplot

Tags: sas

I am concatenating two SAS variables into a single variable that is being used on the y axis of a horizontal box plot (proc sgplot, hbox). I would like this new variable to print in two lines on the axis, does anyone know how to make this happen?

Comment: You're saying you have a variable of like "Height and Weight", values are like "167cm 80kg"?  How exactly does that work - are these ordinal numbers with text in a formatted value containing that, or are these just character strings?

Comment: they are character strings, so in your example i would want the axis to display 167cm in one line and then 80kg in a new line underneath it. I am looking for a way to add a new line character either in the axis statement or in the data step

Comment: I haven't tried it, but 9.4 supports splitchar= for tick values.  http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/grstatproc/67273/HTML/default/viewer.htm#grstatprocwhatsnew94m1.htm

Answer (score 0):

Assuming we have something like :

```
data have;
 call streaminit(7);
 do yvar = "165cm 80kg","168cm 77kg" ,"150cm 50kg", "180cm 90kg";
   do _n_=1 to 10;
     xvar = rand('Normal',35,8);
     output;
   end;
 end;
run;

proc sgplot data=have;
 hbox xvar/category=yvar;
run;
```

It's not possible to split the official axis labels intentionally at a specific spot.  Value labels may be split, but axis labels are not currently.  You would have to create your own axis via the annotate facility.  See https://communities.sas.com/message/134607 for more information.

If you want to look at changing the axis labels through annotation, you can look at http://support.sas.com/kb/49/301.html as a good place to start.  Basically, you need to look at the SGANNO option in SGPLOT, and create a dataset where you use WALLPERCENT (which lets you access the portion of the graph with the label).  The complicating factor is if you are using character strings, it's probably not possible to use DATAVALUE for the y1, so you'd need to calculate using WALLPERCENT or GRAPHPERCENT and know about where each line is (so you'd need to know how many axis labels you need).